# Prove that the set $\{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \mid \text{div} f = 0\}$ of divergence free vector fields is closed in $L^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, distribution-theory, proof-explanation

Let $$C_{0,\sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \mid \operatorname{div}f = 0\}$$
be the set of all divergence free smooth vector fields and define
$$
L_\sigma^2(\mathbb{R}^n) := \overline{C_{0,\sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})}^{\|\cdot\|_2}.
$$

I want to prove the following statement in [Sohr - Navier-Stokes](https://books.google.de/books?id=wWj0BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR4&dq=hermann%20sohr&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> If $n \geq 2$ then 
>   $$
> L_\sigma^2(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \mid \operatorname{div} f = 0\},
> $$
>   i.e.
>   $$
> \overline{\{f \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \mid \operatorname{div}f = 0\}}^{\|\cdot\|_2} = \{f \in \overline{C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)^n}^{\|\cdot\|_2} \mid \operatorname{div}f = 0\}
> $$

The mentioned book provides a proof for both inclusions but the proof for "$\subseteq$" is rather short...

Of course,
$$C_{0,\sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})^n\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R^n})^n$$
and hence
$$C_{0,\sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq L := \{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \mid \operatorname{div} f = 0\}.$$

But is $L$ closed? We can see $L = \ker\,\operatorname{div}$ if we interpret the divergence as mapping
$$
\operatorname{div} \colon L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n \to (C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})^n)'
$$
but I am not sure how to prove continuity of this mapping (author never specified a topology on the target space, maybe weak-*, but anyway this seems to complicated...)

Another perspective on the problem:
Let $f \in C_{0,\sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. 
By definition $\operatorname{div}f = 0$. 
Here, we interpreted the divergence as a linear form on $C_{0, \sigma}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
As a constant and hence continous linear mapping the divergence operator can be extended to the closure of its domain of definition i.e.  $L_\sigma^2(\mathbb{R^n})$.
Of course $$L_\sigma^2(\mathbb{R^n}) \subseteq L_2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$$ but the interpretation of $$\operatorname{div} f = 0$$ in the definition of $L$ is in the sense of distributions, i.e. $$\operatorname{div} f \in (C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R^n}^n)'$$ which is somewhat confusing.

So I have this question: If $\operatorname{div} f = 0$ holds for all $f \in L_\sigma^2$ does it also hold in the distributional sense, i.e. $(\operatorname{div} f )(\varphi) = 0$ for all $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$?

Comment: For $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$, $\text{div}f=0$ means that $\int f\cdot \nabla \phi \, dx = 0$ for all smooth $\phi$ with compact support. Use this to show that if $\text{div}f_n = 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in the $L^2$ sense, then $\text{div}f = 0$. Hint: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Jeff: Thank you, this does the job.